# Problem with Protonvpn when updating packages

Tags: apt, updates

I get this error when trying to  update package with `sudo apt-get update`

```
Hit:1 http://deb.fdmpkg.org bionic InRelease                                   
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease      
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease        
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease      
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease       
Err:7 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                 
      Could not connect to repo.protonvpn.com:443 (10.10.34.35), connection timed out Could not connect to repo.protonvpn.com:443 (10.10.34.35), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                      
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not connect to repo.protonvpn.com:443 (10.10.34.35), connection timed out Could not connect to repo.protonvpn.com:443 (10.10.34.35), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I don't want to use protonvpn and try to uninstall it with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove protonvpn
```

When I do this, I receive this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package protonvpn
```

Update:

there is no line for protonvpn in "Other Software" tab in "Software & Updates" application , but I unchack all lines and when click on close and reload button I get this error:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwHhF.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: You are not reading the error. It is not having an issue with the VPN software. It clearly says it is unable to fetch the VPN software from the vendors site. It is failing on the PPA you added. Remove the PPA from the sources list problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is Jhon Baptist's answer from the discussion, I just want to put it here for others as a proper answer that worked for me, too:

I did fix it with this:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

and the removed all the proton files in the folder, in my case:

```
sudo rm protonvpn-stable.list
sudo rm protonvpn-stable.list.distUpgrade
sudo rm protonvpn-stable.list.save
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to first exclude the ProtonVPN repository from your `apt` sources, then later remove ProtonVPN if you no longer want to use it.

To exclude the ProtonVPN repository via the desktop:

1. Open the "Software & Updates" application:
   [image: Software & Updates]
   <sup>**Note:** Do not confuse this with "Software Updates", which is something different.</sup>
2. Click the "Other Software" tab and find the line that refers to ProtonVPN:
   [image: Other Software Repositories]
3. Uncheck the line for ProtonVPN and press "Close". The system will ask if you want to update, and you can press "Yes" to this.

   <sup>**Note:** The update process is just a `sudo apt update` that runs to ensure the source list on your system is up to date.</sup>

Now you should be able to update your system without the ProtonVPN repository blocking you.

<sub>**Note:** There is nothing in this answer on how to remove ProtonVPN, as the process often breaks networking in an Ubuntu installation. There are some answers on AskUbuntu that have varying degrees of success but, as I am not using ProtonVPN, I cannot say which one is more correct.</sub>

Comment: there is no line for ProtonVPN, but I unchecked all lines and when click on close and reload button, get this error : `error while refreshing cache,couldn't connect to repo.protonvpn.com:443...`

Comment: I am having this exact problem, whitout any difference. There is no line from a proton repository, and any change in the repositories list causes the same warning to prompt. Proton dosent seems to be instaled anywere, but its still causing this warning.

Comment: i did fix it with this : 
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
and the removed all the proton files in the folder (protonvpn-stable.list and protonvpn-stable.list.save)

Comment: @JhonBaptist thank you so much,your solution solved my problem